# Parse multiple .json fields into .txt file onto same lines

Tags: json, jq

I'm using jq to parse a .json file into a text file.

I used:

```
jq -r '.[] | .file_id, .cases[].project.project_id' my_file.json > test6.tx
```

and got a file that looks like this:

```
d47c1aaa
SKCM
5b8564e3
CESC
9b0b7bb0
GBM
```

However, I want it to look like this

```
d47c1aaa  SKCM
5b8564e3  CESC
9b0b7bb0  GBM
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.  Which line in the given output corresponds to .file_id ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, but I will post here in case someone had the same question:

```
jq -r '.[] | "\(.file_id) \(.cases[].project.project_id)"' all_somatic_annotated_TCGA.json > test.txt
```